# Excel, get string value on cell

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

How do I get the cell from a string? I'm counting the number of times a specific string occurs on another worksheet. I have this formula:

```
=COUNTIF('Season 1'!$D$2:$F$1768,"*Player 1*")
```

Instead of having to do this manually with all other players, how do I reference the cell containing the string "Player 1" without having to manually type the string into the formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your list of players starts in cell A1 then try

```
=COUNTIF('Season 1'!$D$2:$F$1768,"*" & A1 & "*")
```

then copy down

Comment: Perfect! Does the asterisks enclosed in double quotes and the ampersands enclosing the cell represent wildcard characters? I haven't used them at all except for now.

Comment: Yes * means any character or any characters or no characters. You had them in your original post so I kept them.

Answer (score 0):

So you don't want to type player 1, 2, 3 etc. into each formula? - in which case type player 1, 2, 3 in cells and then reference them. Like:

```
=COUNTIF('Season 1'!$D$2:$F$1768,"A1") - assuming A1 contains player 1 for example.
```

Is that what you mean? If you could upload the data that would help!

Comment: In this answer, you have `"A1"` in the formula as the second argument instead of just `A1`.  This is a problem because it will search for the string literal "A1" instead of the cell value of `A1`.